# Ajax + Flask for notification dropdown

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, flask

I am trying to implement notification dropdown. 
I am using ajax function that is supposed to take json-ised data of all notifications and update the number of notifications without having to refresh the page. 
However, the function does not work and I am getting no output.

My flask route :

```
@bp.route('/notifications')
@login_required
def notifications():
    since = request.args.get('since', 0.0, type=float)
    notifications = current_user.notifications.filter(
        Notification.timestamp > since).order_by(Notification.timestamp.asc())
    return jsonify([{
        'name': n.name,
        'data': n.get_data(),
        'timestamp': n.timestamp
    } for n in notifications])
```

And my html page:

```
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}    
{% block navbar %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    {% if current_user.is_anonymous %}
                    <li>
                      <a role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                              Notifications {% set new_notifications = current_user.new_notifications() %}
                              <span id="message_count" class="badge"
                              style="visibility: {% if new_notifications %} visible
                                                 {% else %} hidden {% endif %};">
                            {{ new_notifications }}
                        </span>
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" id="dropdown">
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a> 
                            </div>


                    </li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </div>

    </nav>
    <script>

    function set_message_count(n) {
        $('#message_count').text(n);
        $('#message_count').css('visibility', n ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
    }
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
    $(function() {
        var since = 0;
        setInterval(function() {
            $.ajax('{{ url_for('main.notifications') }}?since=' + since).done(
                function(notifications) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < notifications.length; i++) {
                        if (notifications[i].name == 'unread_notifications_count'){
                            set_message_count(notifications[i].data);
                          since = notifications[i].timestamp;}
                    else {
                        let choice = document.createElement("a");
                        let body = document.createTextNode("this is me");
                        choice.appendChild(body);
                        dropdown.appendChild(choice);
                    }

                    }
                }
            );
        }, 10000);
    });
    {% endif %}
    </script>
    {% endblock %}
```

Where am i getting it wrong? 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask route example:

```
@app.route('/example')
def example():
    email = request.args.get('email', 404)
    new_email = example_function(email)
    return jsonify(res=new_email)
```

JS part:

```
$.getJSON('/example', {
    email: "example@example.com"
}, function (data) {
    //data that flask returned
});
```